# ReactJS Unexpected Token ) on Safari only

Tags: javascript, safari, reactjs, gulp

I'm getting an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ")"` on Safari only - this code works on every other browser.

I'm using `gulp` to compile my files as follows:

```
browserify(componentPath + "app.jsx")
    .transform(reactify)
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath));
```

The syntax error is highlighting the following:

```
return React.createElement(If, {
     condition: !_.isEmpty(title)
 }, React.createElement("div", {
     className: "row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading"
 }, React.createElement("div", {
     className: "col-lg-9"
 }, React.createElement("h2", null, title || 'Untitled'), React.createElement("ol", {
     className: "breadcrumb"
 }, React.createElement("li", null, React.createElement("a", {
     onClick: () => self.history.pushState(null, home)
 }, "Home")), links.map(function(link, index) {
     var url = link.url;

     return React.createElement("li", {
         onClick: () => self.history.pushState(null, url),
         key: url,
         className: "ptr-click"
     }, index == links.length - 1 ? React.createElement("strong", null, link.title || 'Untitled') : link.title);
 })))));
```

I commented the whole section out, just to see if it is this particular block of code, but then the error referred to another block of exactly the same `React.createElement`.

Comment: If this code is not further transpiled it is probably due to the `() => {}`.  I don't believe safari can currently execute arrow functions. http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking [mattclemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403990/mattclemens) comment into consideration, Safari currently does not execute arrow functions. So I updated my `gulp` script to:

```
browserify(componentPath + "app.jsx")
    .transform(reactify)
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath));
```

Of course, don't forget to install the presets:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

This worked perfectly, and now my code runs on Safari as well :)